# How do I set the configuration file for only one logger in Log4J

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am working on a library, and want to use Log4J as the logger for debug messages, etc. The only thing is, I don't want to override other people's logging configuration files with my own. I would like to know if or how to set the configuration file for only one logger. My current code looks like this:

```
try {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(assetsFolder + "log4j2.xml");

    ConfigurationSource source = new ConfigurationSource(is);
    Configurator.initialize(null, source);

    LOG = LogManager.getLogger("Slik");
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG = LogManager.getLogger();
    //System.out.println("Failed to initialize the logger");
    LOG.error("Failed to initialize the logger");
    LOG.log(Level.ERROR, e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

But from my understanding, using `Configuration.initialize(null, source);` will set that as the configuration file for all loggers.

Comment: If your shipping your library as an executable jar, I think people can always override your log4j configuration by doing `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///path/To/log4j.properties`.

Comment: So, I am packaging the properties file as a resource. Would people have to run their jar file with that argument if they wanted to use my library?

Comment: So in a project when you say ~Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class)~, it'll look for the closest properties file to the class. If you're shipping a properties file in the jar then by default it will use that file for configuration. You only have to specify the argument if you want to use an external property file

Comment: But, just to make sure, is there any specific way to create a logger with a specific configuration file?